# Continuity of functions of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $\mathbb{R}_l$ be the lower limit topology on the real line generated by the basis $\{[a,b) : a<b\}$, and let $\mathbb{R}$ be the standard topology generated by the basis $\{(a,b) : a<b\}$.

In my rather poorly explained topology notes, in one of the examples it says the addition $\sigma\colon\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}_l \to \mathbb{R}_l$ defined by $\sigma(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous, but not continuous as a function $\sigma\colon\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_l$. Now I get the part of explanation why we have to show that the set $\sigma ^{-1}\bigl([a,b)\bigr)$ is open, but dont know why it is open with respect to the basis  $\{[a,b) \times [c,d)\}$ and not open with respect to $\{[a,b) \times (c,d)\}$.

Could anyone help me clarify why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Update]** More detailed statements are added by OP's request.

It is easy if you use the following Theorem:

> **Definition.** Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a function. We call $f$ is *continuous at* $x\in X$ if for every open set $V\subset Y$ containing $f(x)$, there exists an open set $U\subset X$ containing $x$ such that $f(U)\subset V$.
>
> **Theorem.** A function $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if for every $x\in X$, $f$ is continuous at $x$.

1. By the theorem above, to prove the continuity of the addition $\sigma\colon\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}_l\to\mathbb{R}_l$, it suffices to show that for every $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}_l$, $\sigma$ is continuous at $(a,b)$. Now for any open set $V\subset\mathbb{R}_l$ containing $\sigma(a,b)=a+b$, we need to find an open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}_l$ containing $(a,b)$ such that $\sigma(U)\subset V$. Since $V$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}_l$ containing $a+b$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that (a basis element) $[a+b,(a+b)+\epsilon)\subset V$. We can choose an open set
   $$
   U=[a,a+\tfrac{\epsilon}{2})\times[b,b+\tfrac{\epsilon}{2})\subset\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}_l
   $$
   containing $(a,b)$. Then $\sigma(U)=[a+b,(a+b)+\epsilon)\subset V$. $\quad\square$
2. We will show that the addition $\sigma\colon\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_l$ is not continuous at any $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}$. Fix a point $(a,b)$. By the theorem above, to prove the discontinuity of $\sigma$ at $(a,b)$, we need to show that there exists an open set $V\subset\mathbb{R}_l$ containing $\sigma(a,b)=a+b$ such that for any open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}$ containing $(a,b)$, $\sigma(U)\not\subset V$. Now choose an open set
   $$
   V=[a+b,(a+b)+\tfrac{1}{2})\subset\mathbb{R}_l
   $$
   containing $(a,b)$. (You can choose any positive real number other than $\frac{1}{2}$.)
   For any open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}$ containing $(a,b)$, we can find a basis element in $U$ satisfying
   $$
   (a,b) \in [a,a+\epsilon)\times(b-\delta,b+\delta)\subset U
   $$
   for some $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$. Then
   $$
   \sigma\bigl([a,a+\epsilon)\times(b-\delta,b+\delta)\bigr)=\bigl((a+b)-\delta,(a+b)+\epsilon+\delta\bigr)\not\subset[a+b,(a+b)+\tfrac{1}{2})=V
   $$
   because the points less than $a+b$ are not contained in $V$. It follows that $\sigma(U)\not\subset V$. $\quad\square$
3. Here is another proof showing that the addition $\sigma\colon\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_l$ is not continous. Assume that $\sigma$ is continuous. Then the image of the connected set $C=\{0\}\times(a,b)$ by $\sigma$ must be connected. But we have a contradiction that $\sigma(C)=(a,b)$ is not connected, because $(a,b)=(a,\frac{a+b}{2})\cup[\frac{a+b}{2},b)$ can be written as the disjoint union of two nonempty open sets. (In fact, $\mathbb{R}_l$ is totally disconnected.)

Comment: Thank you for this helpful response. I was just wondering it might be a very simple problem, however I was wondering, the set $[a,b) \times [c,d),$ what does this actually denote, does this denote a square?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis You're welcome. Actually $[a,b)\times[c,d)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a square without the upper and the right borders.

Comment: Ok I see, I have another question, for the proof of 1, why cant we choose some interval $[a,a+\epsilon/2)\times[b-\delta,b+\epsilon/2)?$

Comment: @AuroraBorealis If you choose $U=[a,a+\epsilon/2)\times[b-\delta,b+\epsilon/2)$, $\sigma(U)=[(a+b)-\delta,(a+b)+\epsilon)\not\subset V=[a+b,(a+b)+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Yes, so how come we can choose $b-\delta$ in 2, but we cant do that in 1? By choosing $b-\delta$ in $1,$ then that would also imply that it is not continuous? So like I am confused on what forbids us from actually not being able to choose $b-\delta $ for 1.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis My previous comment had a false statement that $V=[a+b,(a+b)+\epsilon)$. It should be read as $\not\subset[a+b,(a+b)+\epsilon)\subset V$. Anyway, for (1) it suffices to find only one $U$ satisfying $\sigma(U)\subset V$. But for (2) you must show that for every $U$, $\sigma(U)\not\subset V$. It may be a good exercise for you.

Comment: Ok, I am still not sure how I can do that part. Could you please assist me again?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis I gave more statements. Hope you follow my statements.

Comment: Yes, thank you now I fully understand this problem.

Comment: But for part 2, why cant we have $\sigma(U) = [a+b-\delta, a+b+\epsilon+\delta^{'} )?$

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Notice that I dropped $\delta'$. Anyway $U$ is now arbitrary. So we have $\sigma(U)\supset\bigl((a+b)-\delta,(a+b)+\epsilon+\delta\bigr)$ and it is enough to show $\sigma(U)\not\subset V$.